# Django allauth facebook

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, django-allauth

I am using allauth for social authentication of my django app. Whenever I try to login using facebook I get the following message -

`Social Network Login Failure
An error occurred while attempting to login via your social network account.`

And the following URL gets called -

[http://localhost:8000/accounts/facebook/login/callback/?code=AQCh7KVCn6wkBYA-_JWcalpS5buACpdy-91N8BcAJPqfKuMAXPTk8aoZCLsjA-wYg_Q2fKd8zgg5ERSmmzwG4_U1SX8gtlyydCSUNvvbsu4Pfw0VugMQL0avDJJz-tkVU5GJc7QucOIfAbIcQBUpldSk2NFz7rB6fcWH3D0lCab0CBtmJ-vTztiS30mjbIaaspdx7RF5bm75iUmU9Q6rbmBls9AIPTuNMLVUpRUj8LJTBxW_57v307ZbuGQYVQ69Fq10BYdsHdiqPlrNahV5ddipjCz4u6cfeMRvWJ-M9RF__85Dc0sFwie5Uy1G1-3l5D4_LiusvMWsPs4hffIW9-3LtehKdOg2f3y54HZOluvcChVm0jEJ2Se5NUHjR4c3PdCeHXSD0CvG9q0QvTosDKZXKfwxbGtQ43mlKf2odPTZoA3vjCbIji_Gd2nszzrdp2g&state=Gp1uObhfZm4t#*=*](http://localhost:8000/accounts/facebook/login/callback/?code=AQCh7KVCn6wkBYA-_JWcalpS5buACpdy-91N8BcAJPqfKuMAXPTk8aoZCLsjA-wYg_Q2fKd8zgg5ERSmmzwG4_U1SX8gtlyydCSUNvvbsu4Pfw0VugMQL0avDJJz-tkVU5GJc7QucOIfAbIcQBUpldSk2NFz7rB6fcWH3D0lCab0CBtmJ-vTztiS30mjbIaaspdx7RF5bm75iUmU9Q6rbmBls9AIPTuNMLVUpRUj8LJTBxW_57v307ZbuGQYVQ69Fq10BYdsHdiqPlrNahV5ddipjCz4u6cfeMRvWJ-M9RF__85Dc0sFwie5Uy1G1-3l5D4_LiusvMWsPs4hffIW9-3LtehKdOg2f3y54HZOluvcChVm0jEJ2Se5NUHjR4c3PdCeHXSD0CvG9q0QvTosDKZXKfwxbGtQ43mlKf2odPTZoA3vjCbIji_Gd2nszzrdp2g&state=Gp1uObhfZm4t#_=_)

I am currently working on it so the domain is localhost. Could someone plesae help me out here? I tried finding a solution to this problem but all in vain.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide more details? Local errors by django can't be reproduced, so your link does not provide any information.
did you put localhost in your facebook app domain?

Comment: Yeah, localhost was in the facebook app domain. What I was doing wrong was accessing the login URL as 127:0:0:1/accounts/login/ instead of localhost/accounts/login/ and that worked. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

What I was doing wrong was accessing the login URL as 127:0:0:1/accounts/login/ instead of localhost/accounts/login/ and that worked. Thanks anyway!